# Special characters do not appear with epigrafica.sty in LaTeX

Tags: fonts

Special characters do not appear using `epigrafica` package in LaTeX. Header is as follows:

```
\documentclass[Alon1,ChapterTOCs,11pt]{Alon} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{epigrafica} 
\usepackage[LGR,OT1]{fontenc} 
\makeindex 
\title{Test epigrafica font} 
\author{Author} 

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle% 
\tableofcontents 
\mainmatter 
\chapterauthor{Author Na\"eas\"ur`e\'e}{India} 
\chapter{Chapter title} 
A component is picked at random from the assembly line. \section{Introduction} A component is picked at random from the assembly line. 
\begin{itemize} 
\item Procedual knowledge (``knowing what") One family considers a privacy. 
\end{itemize} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on what you mean with special characters and how you try to add them? Could be everything. Thanks.

Comment: Where's the `Alon` class available?

Comment: I'm really curious why people insist on using non-Unicode TeX engines in 2015. I'm sorry, but do you like pain? Use LuaTeX/XeTeX with UTF-8 and OpenType fonts!

Comment: @MartinSchröder And those don't bring their own pain? Compiling with XeLaTeX, in particular, is bad. I cannot leave the machine if I start a compilation because I'm too concerned about my machine overheating as it gobbles every resource if I've made a mistake. I don't know if this would really happen: presumably the hardware would shut-off. But it makes me nervous as hell. And LuaTeX is just too dangerous for regular use since it amounts to running with shell escape enabled all the time.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Of course, if I needed something like Hebrew, it might be different. But for Western European languages, including some Greek, pdfTeX is still the best option for me by a significant margin.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not relevant anymore but I just struggled with the same issue. 
Declare the special character you want to include before you start the document with:

`\DeclareTextAccent{\'}{OT1}{180}`

Then in the text you can write Cafe with accent as
`caf\'e`

Here is a link to all the definitions you can add in epigrafica: http://tug.ctan.org/fonts/greek/epigrafica/tex/epigrafica.sty

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Surely this is defined by default??

Comment: Did not work by default. (Maybe the default settings are different in other document classes. I am working in report.)